# Getting "None" instead of list of values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on POC on Alibaba Cloud and not authorized to share the information. I am a beginner in python. Let me consider an example to address my issue.

I am getting `none` instead of list of values,

Example code:

```
NumSet={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
NumList = list(NumSet).reverse()
print(NumList)
```

Output:

`None`

What I am missing?

Comment: the ``.reverse()`` method doesn't return anything, it directly change the list.

Comment: The most pythonic way to reverse a list is `NumList[::-1]`. You don't need any `reverse` or other routines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.reverse()` reverses the list **in-place** and returns nothing (or returns `None`).

```
NumList = list(NumSet)  # convert to list first
NumList.reverse()  # reverse in-place
```

This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: It should also be noted that if you need not-in-place reversal, you can iterate over `reversed(list(NumSet))`.

Comment: @AKX What does `set()` in your code do?

Comment: Derp, I had misread the set-to-list conversion as being the other way around. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

list.reverse() doesn't return the list reversed. What it does is reversing the list in-place. Just change to this and it ill work

```
NumSet = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
NumList = list(NumSet)
NumList.reverse()
print(NumList)
```